# How to edit a text file using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, edit, txt

I have a text file that is in the following form:

```
"1981-02-01",15.3
"1981-02-02",18.8
"1981-02-03",21.9
"1981-02-04",19.9
```

I want to edit these two line and make it like as shown below:

```
1       15.3
2       18.8
3       21.9
4       19.9
```

I am looking for a MATLAB function that does this automatically without having to change my file manually because the original file contains 500 lines.
thank you

Comment: There's not such a function. You need to write it yourself. Read file, do type conversions as needed and write in a new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment above suggested there isn't such a function built into MATLAB. Writing your own function/script is the best option. Below is a script that reads the second column of the text file and creates the first column of the text file named `Column_1`. The `Data` is then written written to a text file using the `fprintf()` function.

```
File_Name = "Text.txt";
Format_File(File_Name);

%Function definition%
function [] = Format_File(File_Name)

T = readtable(File_Name);

Column_1 = 1:height(T);
Column_2 = ((T{:,2}));

Data(1,:) = Column_1;
Data(2,:) = Column_2;

fileID = fopen('Text.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID,'%d   %.1f\n',Data);
fclose(fileID);

end
```

---

### Input: Text.txt

```
"1981-02-01",15.3
"1981-02-02",18.8
"1981-02-03",21.9
"1981-02-04",19.9
```

### Output: Text.txt

```
1   15.3
2   18.8
3   21.9
4   19.9
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, happy to help. :)